# C# AutoMapper simplification

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Is there any way to simplify mapping? I wouldn't like to write `src.Accounts.First().UserInfo` accessing several times. It would be nice to put it in a separate variable. How to do it?

```
CreateMap<Test, TestDto>()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Accounts.First().UserInfo.FirstName))
    .ForMember(dst => dst.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Accounts.First().UserInfo.LastName))
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Email, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Accounts.First().UserInfo.Email));
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IncludeMembers`.

```
CreateMap<Test, TestDto>().IncludeMembers(src => src.Accounts.First().UserInfo);
```

https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers

Answer (score 0):

You can seek [Custom Type Converters](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html).

```cs
public class TestDtoTypeResolver : ITypeConverter<Test, TestDto>
{
    public TestDto Convert(Test source, TestDto destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var userInfo = source.Accounts.First().UserInfo;
        return new TestDto
        {
            FirstName = userInfo.FirstName, 
            LastName = userInfo.LastName, 
            Email = userInfo.Email
        };
    }
}
```

```cs
CreateMap<Test, TestDto>()
    .ConvertUsing<TestDtoTypeResolver>();
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/agfqfZ)